# Finding maximum value of an expression $3a+4b$ where $(a,b)$ lies on unit circle.

Tags: optimization, circles, coordinate-systems

If the point $(a,b)$ lies on circle $x^2+y^2=1$ then maximum value of $3a+4b$ is ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $x=sin (t),y=cos (t) $ thus we need max value of $3sin (t)+4cos (t)\leq \sqrt {3^2+4^2}=5$

Comment: We need a maximum, so what is the value of $t$ such that $3\sin t + 4 \cos t = 5$?

Comment: $sint=3/5$ or $37degrees $

Comment: And why does one want $t $ when we are just asked about maximum value

Comment: To be sure it's a maximum, not an upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

$$3a+4b=(3,4).(a,b)\le \sqrt{25\times (a^2+b^2)}=5$$

---

In general $$(x.y)^2 \le |x|.|y|$$

and equality holds iff $x,y$ be parallel vectors.